# codename-one.appspot.com 500 error when attempting to migrate old device id

Tags: push-notification, codenameone

When I execute
    curl -i "https://codename-one.appspot.com/token?m=id&i=d116845c6825ac151489ab33725285e5f48b3e0225285e5f48b3e02"

The result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 3f022af7dc49c7650be2fa82421a8511
Date: Tue, 06 Jun 2017 18:25:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 323
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="38,37,36,35"


<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

This seems to happen when running the example (with six 9s) from https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-push-servers.html

How can I tell if an old device id exists or if this is a temporary error with the servers?

Answer (score 0):

That id is incorrect as the old device ids were purely numeric and your number contains both a `d` and an `e` character

Comment: That was the issue. For some reason the DeviceIDs were not prefixed with cn1-ios or cn1-gcm. Is there any documentation on the push server? Now we are receiving: HTTP 200 with "status":"inactive"

Comment: We're still receiving `status=inactive` for ios devices. Is there anyway to test for inactive keys without attempting to send a push notification?

Comment: I think you are using this API incorrectly. This API is for converting old legacy push ID's and I think you are trying to "convert" the arguments for the registration callback which isn't necessary